# How to avoid borrowing twice?

Tags: rust

I am having trouble wrapping my head around the borrowing going on in the example below. Both `find_command_by_name` and `find_command_by_alias` borrow `&mut self`. `self` refers to a `CommandManager` which contains commands as fields, so I understand that if I have some `&mut Command` field I cannot access its parent `&mut self` anymore since that would be violating having two mutable pointers to the same object.

However, what if `cmd` is `None`? In that case, there is no second mutable pointer, but the borrow checker is still telling me I cannot use `&mut self` anymore. How can I ensure that I am not borrowing twice, or tell the borrow checker that `&mut self` is actually safe to use?

Any design patterns to help with this sort of problem are appreciated.

```
fn find_command(&mut self, input : &Vec<String>) -> Option<&mut Command> {
    let mut cmd = self.find_command_by_name(input);
            
    if cmd.is_some() {
        return cmd
    }

    let cmd = self.find_command_by_alias(input); // Error - self is being borrowed twice!

    return cmd
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this should be allowed.  It is a [longstanding bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21906).

There are a few workarounds, one of which is to forcibly unbind the reference from the lifetime of `&mut self` by using `unsafe`.  Note that the lifetimes are still bound together from the perspective of the caller, so this doesn't create a safety issue for users of this function.

```
fn find_command<'a>(&'a mut self, input : &Vec<String>) -> Option<&'a mut Command> {
    let cmd = self.find_command_by_name(input);

    if cmd.is_some() {
        return cmd.map(|v| unsafe { &mut *(v as *mut _) });
    }

    let cmd = self.find_command_by_alias(input); // Error - self is being borrowed twice!

    cmd
}
```

Pointers don't have lifetimes associated with them, so casting the reference to a pointer and then back to a reference "disconnects" them.  The cast-and-borrow is an opaque wall to the borrow checker.

Of course, this throws a bit of safety out the window, so you need to be careful when editing this code later.  In particular, you need to be sure that you're giving a reference that's valid for `'a` to the unsafe block.

Another workaround is safer, but repeats the first operation:

```
fn find_command<'a>(&'a mut self, input : &Vec<String>) -> Option<&'a mut Command> {
    match self.find_command_by_name(input) {
        Some(_) => self.find_command_by_name(input),
        None => self.find_command_by_alias(input)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it not possible to instead capture the value inside `Some(_)` (e.g. `Some(v)`) and return it? If this isn't an option for some reason, it's a shame Rust doesn't allow for anything better than opaque, unsafe code, or suffer a performance loss. (though I suppose the code might also be able to be refactored to avoid this issue entirely?)

Comment: @OctaveL As I said in the very first paragraph, this _should_ be allowed but currently isn't due to a bug, which is scheduled to be fixed sometime this year (when Polonius, the next-gen borrow checker, is ready).

Comment: One day I'll stop reading things too fast.. Thanks for your answer. I also hadn't heard about Polonius, that sounds exciting

Comment: @OctaveL I'm very excited for it to land! It will help make many safe-but-currently-rejected borrowing patterns possible.